# How to add path from folder below cwd in matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

Let's say I have a folder structure like this

```
 -----A------file1.m
 M
 -----B------file2.m
```

So I have a folder M which has 2 subfolders A and B, and they both have one file.

Now I want to use file1.m in file2.m, how can I add folder M/A to a path??

I am using

```
addpath('C:\Users\rysza\M\A)
```

in file2.m.

But I would like the scripts to work  when others copy them at their local computer.

Comment: What matters is the fact that the source files of your code are divided in two folders, A and B; the fact that in your PC are under the folder M is a choice rather a requirement unless the folder M contains other source files needed to make A and B script working. If all the scirpt are only in A and B, each user has simply to add the two folders to its own path (cont. in the next comment)

Comment: Adding the instruction to add a folder to the path in one of the script does not seems a good idea. The other users do not  necessarily need to replicate your structure (A and B under M) neither the name of the folders (unless they are somehow referenced in the scripts). Any way, it also possible to replicate the structure and add the root folder (M) with its subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

If A and B will always be in the same position relative to each other, then you can use relative folders. e.g.

```
addpath( fullfile( '..', 'A' ) )
```